# Laravel homestead links to same directory

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm setting up homestead. But when I want to add another website to homestead it points to the same directory?

This is my Homestead.yaml file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/documents/vagrant/sites
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: test.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/test
    - map: testt.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/secondtest
databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

When I go to testt.app it points to the same directory as test.app. This is how my etc/hosts file looks like:

[image]

My homestead directory:

[image]

Every time I make changes in my homestead.yaml file I do: "vagrant provision". When I ssh into my homestead server I can go to the directory secondtest so it exists.

Comment: I'm having this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your `etc/hosts` you should point both domains to `192.168.10.10` IP and not `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Already tried that. When I do this it's telling me: "webpages is not available".

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually run the provision command?

`homestead provision`

Comment: do you mean vagrant provision? When I do homestead provision in my homestead directory it's telling me:command not found

Comment: yes, I think I may have set up an alias for that, so yeah, `vagrant provision` from within your Homestead directory. As per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead#adding-additional-sites)